# How can I delete the default delivery and garbage zones?

Tags: prison-architect

I am trying to remove the default delivery and garbage zones, but none of the demolish options let me.

How can I delete the default delivery and garbage zones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Delivery and Garbage areas are considered rooms. To remove them, select the rooms icon, and right click and drag the area. You can then re-place the delivery and garbage area wherever you like (though I imagine they would only work correctly next to the road)

Comment: Please note that you need s delivery zone for your prison to receive any input such as prisoners or material